# How do I load multiple tables into a Django View?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm working through my first Django project (aside from a couple tutorials) and am stuck on how to accomplish this.  For simplicity I'll use an Excel analogy to explain what I'm trying to do.  I have 7 buttons across row 1 (TOP Model).  Clicking on any of those buttons then brings up a list of 5 items in column A (SIDE Model) which all have corresponding items in rows 2-6 (BODY Model).  In the View I can get the SIDE Model to load through the TOP Model primary key, but can't figure out how to connect the BODY Model since it's dependent on the SIDE Model.

VIEW

```
def details(request, pk):
    top = TOP.objects.filter().order_by('-modified_date')
    middle= MIDDLE.objects.filter(TOP_id__pk=pk)
    body = BODY.objects.filter(??????????)
   return render(request, 'details.html', {'top': top, 'middle': middle,
                                                      'body': body})
```

MODEL

```
class TOP(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class MIDDLE(models.Model):
    TOP= models.ForeignKey('mysite.TOP', related_name='middle')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BODY(models.Model):
    TOP= models.ForeignKey('mysite.TOP', related_name='indicators')
    MIDDLE= models.ForeignKey('mysite.MIDDLE', related_name='indicators')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

TEMPLATE

```
{% block content %}
<div>

    <div class="TOP-container">
        {% for tops in top %}
            <div class="tops"><a href="{% url 'details' pk=tops.pk %}">{{ tops.title }}</a></div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>

    {% for middles in middle %}
        <div class="middle-container">
            <div class="middles">{{ middles.title }}</div>
            {% for bodys in body %}
                <div class="bodys">{{ body.title }}</div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the middle and body objects using the foreign key related name.

If I understand your question correctly:

- You only want to display `MIDDLE` (`SIDE`) elements associated with the selected TOP element.
- You only want to display `BODY` elements associated with the displayed `MIDDLE` elements

To accomplish this you need to:

1. Keep track of which `TOP` element is selected
2. Loop through only the `MIDDLE` object with a foreign key pointing to this `TOP` object

Therefore, your loop will look like this:

```
{% for middle in selected_top.middle.all %}
    <div class="middle-container">
        <div class="middles">{{ middle.title }}</div>
        {% for body in middle.indicators.all %}
            <div class="bodys">{{ body.title }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Note the template syntax used to access the foreign key by its `related_name`:

```
<object>.<related_name>.all
```

A few other notes:

- Its standard to use a plural variable name to represent a set of objects and a singular name to represent a single element in the set; you did the opposite
- You are mixing the use of `MIDDLE` and `TOP`
- You only need to pass the set of `TOP` objects to the view

Comment: That was pretty painless and makes complete sense, thanks!  I've also corrected the use of single/plural variable names, which definitely reads better now.  I've been using the Django Girls Tutorial project that I completed previously and they had them flipped, so thanks for pointing that out.